# update KeyboardAvoidingView after a layout change

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I have a form in my app that has a floating bar with buttons that animates into the view at the bottom of the window when the user makes any change to any of the data in the form. I have this bar rendering relative to the height of the window so it knows when the keyboard is open or closed and will attach to wherever the bottom of the view window is at any give time.

The issue I have is the form is wrapped in a `KeyboardAvoidingView` around the form with a behavior of `padding` and this all works great, however when I make my change and my floating button bar comes up, because the input is at the bottom of the window the bar now covers up the input I'm typing in.

I haven't been able to find a way to fix this yet. I tried disabling the `KeyboardAvoidingView` I assume that maybe I need to somehow tell the view about this bar that's covering up part of the view but I'm not sure how I do that.

here is a snapshot of what this looks like for reference...

[image]

[image]